# Linked Geo Data seems to contain only a few of all housenumbers of OSM. How can it be?

Tags: sparql, geocoding, openstreetmap, linked-data

I have a question regarding the retrieval of the house numbers from Open Street Map through the [Linked Geo Data](http://linkedgeodata.org/About) [sparql endpoint](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql):

If I run a query to select all the buildings which have a  house number located in the city of, for example, of Esino Lario I get only 11 results whereas in OSM seems that a lot of building of that village have explicitly indicated a housenumber (compare the [query result](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org&query=Select%20*%0D%0AWhere%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fs%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2Faddr%253Acity%3E%20%22Esino%20Lario%22%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2Faddr%253Ahousenumber%3E%20%3Fhousenumber.%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on) with the [actual view from OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=17/45.99498/9.33471)).

Even if i expand my search to the whole world broadening the research to include all possibilities I get only 1,176,404 results which seems not reasonable at all ([here the query result](http://linkedgeodata.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org&query=Select%20count%28%3Fhousenumber%20%29%20as%20%3Fn%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Where%20%7B%20%3Fs%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Flinkedgeodata.org%2Fontology%2Faddr%253Ahousenumber%3E%20%3Fhousenumber%20%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on)).

The queries used are the following:

```
Select *
Where {
?s
    <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/addr%3Acity> "Esino Lario";
    <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/addr%3Ahousenumber> ?housenumber.
}
```

and

```
Select count(?housenumber ) as ?n
Where { ?s  <http://linkedgeodata.org/ontology/addr%3Ahousenumber> ?housenumber }
```

Seems that the LGD database is not complete or not updated at Jan 2016 as declared. Or, which is more plausible, I am doing some bad mistakes in the query or I do not understand properly the ontology used.

Can somebody please help me unravel this mystery?

Comment: Did you try to ask the Linked Geo Data people whether they include all related OSM data? Is querying OSM data directly an option for you? E.g. by using [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Comment: Thank you @scai for your contribution. I've tried to write in their google group, but is not very frequented and I have not yet received any response. 
I've learned from experience that stackoverflow is often the best choice because is by far the most popular.

Using directly OSM form me is feasible but not convenient.  A 5-star data source for OSM would simplify a lot my application